SharePoint Item to pdf using SharePoint REST API
Objective is that. I am tring to read the Item of a list using Rest API and want to save that item details to pdf which should be similar to the item details UI when the item is opened in Modal or edit dialog box shown in 2nd image.

So Now when I click on the title a modal opens with information of the item as seen the below image.

The content in  the Modal has a standard structure may be as per column order but is there any way or is there any default form design to read here with REST API so that it can be writen similar to html and then that html we can convert it to pdf if we get the form structure , I am not sure if this possible to get the structure of opened item details.
Requirement is because some times this default structure is customised also in that case how to fetch the positions of fields order or customised chronology or sometimes the form is designed in sharepoint designer to show the item in customised way with tabs.
Any idea to read this details structure with REST API?
would be helpful if there is any alternative. I am using rest api to read the list items and fields .
Currently I store all the feild values of an item in a json file.
